# How to restrict pancakeswap users from adding initial liquidity for my issued token?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, binance-smart-chain

I plan to launch a token, but I can not add liquidity right away, because first audit will be processed and presale. Thus I am thinking how to prevent other pancakeswap users from adding initial liquidity for my token? Which function I should use for that?
I am thinking maybe transfer function should have some kind of whitelisting, so transfer would be possible only by token owner and presale contract.
Please share your experience with such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thus I am thinking how to prevent other pancakeswap users from adding initial liquidity for my token?

Correct. You cannot prevent trading of your token if your token is transferable.

[Here is an example how you can modify transfer() function with restrict conditions](https://github.com/miohtama/smart-contracts/blob/master/contracts/CentrallyIssuedToken.sol#L71).

Answer (score 1):

Just set 100% of the total supply to the owner account. That way nobody can supply more liquidity because nobody else owns the token at the present time.

Answer (score 0):

you have to restrict the function using a require:

```
contract Airdrop {
  address public admin;
...
}
    
constructor(address _token, address _admin) {
        admin = _admin; 
        token = IERC20(_token);
      }
    
     function addinitial(uint amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == admin, 'only admin');
        your function to add liquidities;
      }
```

Comment: this would not work, as you have to check transfer function and transfer function has to be public for everyone. I guess i just need to have some boolean set like "launched", and if not, then disable trading and only check if user is admin, if admin, mean he/she adding liquidity and after that toggle the boolean so everyone can transfer

Comment: The function is public but as the admin address is stored in the constructor and the require verify if the message sender is the admin, it will block anyone else to add liquidities.
using the constructor to store the admin address is one of the best practices to restrict access to functions.
look at this example:
https://github.com/jklepatch/eattheblocks/blob/master/blockchain-masterclass/dex-1-smart-contract/5-wallet/Dex.sol