# How to restrict PancakeSwap users from adding new pair on my new token's LP?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, liquid, pool, pancakeswap

## **Hi there**

(I'm new to the world of crypto and I'm still a noob and confused so please help me with your answer)
As a note I have read this:
[How to restrict pancakeswap users from adding initial liquidity for my issued token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063009/how-to-restrict-pancakeswap-users-from-adding-initial-liquidity-for-my-issued-to)

**Let's look at this scenario:**
Bob created and launched a new token on BSC with 1000 total supply with name "test".
Bob also created a new pair with 80% of the total supply with 800 wbnb (test800 / 800 wbnb).
So each test token worth 1 wbnb and Instead, he receives 20 new LP-tokens.
Bob burned all the LP tokens by sending them to Dead-Wallet (or used any other locking platform), so far so good.

As nowadays everybody know, whenever someone trades on PancakeSwap, the trader pays a 0.25% fee, of which 0.17% is added to the Liquidity Pool of the swap pair they traded on.
https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/products/pancakeswap-exchange/pancakeswap-pools

A new buyer arrives, buys 100 of my tokens (test) and opens a new pair 100test/300wbnb (Or the same old LP is used) what will happen ?

> Will my token price increase?
>
> What if a new buyer creates a new pair with USDT?
>
> How do I create an initial price for my new token?
>
> Is it my first LP that creates my initial token price or the second
> LP?

**My most important question is:**

> **How can I limit and restrict my LP from adding new pairs by others?**

with thanks

I searched a lot on the internet, but no one mentioned it, or at least it was not simple or understandable for an amateur like me. I tried it myself on the Testnet network. The initial price of my coins was built according to my initial pool, but apparently everything changed when I built the second pool.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I limit and restrict my LP from adding new pairs by others?

You cannot. If a token is transferable, it is also freely tradeable.

Comment: The function is public but as the admin address is stored in the constructor and the require verify if the message sender is the admin, it will block anyone else to add liquidities. using the constructor to store the admin address is one of the best practices to restrict access to function.

Comment: look at this example: https://github.com/jklepatch/eattheblocks/blob/master/blockchain-masterclass/dex-1-smart-contract/5-wallet/Dex.sol